# Copy Asana Project to Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, zapier, asana

I already have Zapier copying new tasks in Asana to a Google Sheets, but what I really need is a dump of ALL tasks (and due dates, etc.) from a given Asana project to a Google Sheets. From there, my Zap would be able to maintain the Sheets, especially if I had a second Zap to find and sync state-change.

In any case, I need a way to make printable/sharable "lists" of all Asana tasks within a given project; Asana's print an export options are simply LACKING.

Comment: You've tried exporting to CSV?

Comment: A possible workaround could be to sync your tasks with your google calendar, and then extract that data from your calendar in into a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to sync a project to Google Sheets:

[image]

Comment: I will. To date all of our accounts are based on our work emails (Exchange) and not our Google Apps logins. The two are not tied together via SSO. Any advice as to how I can migrate an Asana account from one email address/auth to another (Google)?

Comment: In fact, even when logging into Asana with a second Google ID, I'm not presented the option you have in the screencap above. Does the team owner need to be Google auth'd?

Comment: Try adding a new email address to your Asana domain by going to My Profile Settings > From Email and then clicking "+ Add New Email".  If this doesn't merge the emails, you will need to write into Asana support.

Comment: It seems like the "built-in" integration between Asana and Sheets requires at minimum a paid business plan.  How-to here: https://asana.com/apps/google-sheets